# laravel 5 belongsToMany Error after composer update

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am getting error after composer update

> QueryException in Connection.php line 636:
>   SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'war_id' in 'where clause'

I have 3 tables in many to many relationship

1. wars table

> id - int pk

2. locations table

> id - int pk

3. war_locations table

> id - int pk
>   war_id int
>   location_id int

war_locations table is pivot table.

I have declared relation ship in model

War.php

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Location', 'war_locations', 'war_id', 'location_id');
}
```

But when i try to get location of a war then it fails.

```
$wars = War::with('locations')->where('status',1)->get();
```

It was working before composer update

I dont know why it is trying to find war_id in pivot table.
Complete exception:

```
`PDOException in Connection.php line 310:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'war_id' in 'where clause'
in Connection.php line 310
at PDO->prepare('select * from `wc_locations` where `war_id` = ?') in Connection.php line 310
at Connection->Illuminate\Database\{closure}(object(MySqlConnection), 'select * from `wc_locations` where `war_id` = ?', array('2')) in Connection.php line 629
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `wc_locations` where `war_id` = ?', array('2'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 596
at Connection->run('select * from `wc_locations` where `war_id` = ?', array('2'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 315
at Connection->select('select * from `wc_locations` where `war_id` = ?', array('2'), true) in Builder.php line 1389
at Builder->runSelect() in Builder.php line 1379
at Builder->getFresh(array('*')) in Builder.php line 1364
at Builder->get(array('*')) in Builder.php line 409
at Builder->getModels() in BelongsToMany.php line 176
at BelongsToMany->get() in BelongsToMany.php line 99
at BelongsToMany->getResults() in Model.php line 2699
at Model->getRelationshipFromMethod('locations') in Model.php line 2665
at Model->getRelationValue('locations') in Model.php line 2607
at Model->getAttribute('locations') in Model.php line 3325
at Model->__get('locations') in War.php line 102
at War->getLocationListAttribute(null) in Model.php line 2722
at Model->mutateAttribute('location_list', null) in Model.php line 2734
at Model->mutateAttributeForArray('location_list', null) in Model.php line 2494
at Model->attributesToArray() in Model.php line 2434
at Model->toArray() in Collection.php line 902
at Collection->Illuminate\Support\{closure}(object(War))
at array_map(object(Closure), array(object(War), object(War), object(War), object(War), object(War), object(War))) in Collection.php line 904
at Collection->toArray() in Collection.php line 914
at Collection->jsonSerialize()
at json_encode(object(Collection)) in 6823600b52dddc7dc45dcf9b454ab6d0 line 559
at include('/home/aditya/public_html/warcircle/storage/framework/views/6823600b52dddc7dc45dcf9b454ab6d0') in PhpEngine.php line 42
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/home/aditya/public_html/warcircle/storage/framework/views/6823600b52dddc7dc45dcf9b454ab6d0', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'wars' => object(Collection), 'user' => null, 'trendingWars' => array(object(War), object(War)), 'topWars' => object(Collection))) in CompilerEngine.php line 58
at CompilerEngine->get('/home/aditya/public_html/warcircle/resources/views/site/home/index.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'wars' => object(Collection), 'user' => null, 'trendingWars' => array(object(War), object(War)), 'topWars' => object(Collection))) in View.php line 138
at View->getContents() in View.php line 107
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 81
at View->render() in Response.php line 51
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 202
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1225
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 113
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 114
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(HomeController), object(Route), object(Request), 'index') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 69
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\Site\HomeController', 'index') in Route.php line 201
at Route->runWithCustomDispatcher(object(Request)) in Route.php line 134
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 704
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 706
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 671
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 42
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54`
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the keys in your relationship are in the wrong order. Try swapping war_id and location_id like so:

```
public function locations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Location', 'war_locations', 'location_id', 'war_id');
}
```

Comment: I have tried that but same error with location_id .  `QueryException in Connection.php line 636: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'location_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Double check that the keys you specify exist as column names in the war_locations table. This error happens when you are referencing a column name that doesn't exist on the table you are querying.